# Determine all $m \in \mathbb F$ sucht that $V_m := \{(y_1, y_2, y_3) \in \mathbb F^3 | y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = m \} \subset \mathbb F^3$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Determine all $m \in \mathbb F$ such that  $V_m := \{(y_1, y_2, y_3) \in \mathbb F^3 | y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = m \}  \subset \mathbb F^3$ is a subspace.

My suggestion is, that is only true for $m = 0 $, because the zero element must be in $V_m$ if $V_m$ is a subspace. But I cannot find a proof for that. And is it possible that a zero element is not of the following form: $(0_1,......,0_n)$ for each $\mathbb F^n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V_m$ be a subspace .Then $(0,0,0)\in V_m\implies m=0+0+0 \implies m=0$

Conversely ,$V_0$ is always a subspace.

Comment: Okay but is m = 0 the only solution?

Comment: @ChangWoo;Yes I have shown that only

Comment: @ChangWoo; Please accept the answer if it served you